# Will getting UK student visa cancel my current Tier 2 ICT visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, immigration, student-visa, uk-visa

**Background:**
I am working in UK on ICT Tier 2 Visa which is ending on 31st August. But, I am planning to join university on 14th or 21st September. I can apply for Student visa 3 months prior to start of course. and Home office takes 8 weeks to make a decision.

**Scenario:**
Suppose I consider 14th September as course start date and apply for student visa on 14th July within UK. Though it takes 8 weeks for decision, if I get it in 2 weeks then:

- Will my current Tier 2 visa stand cancelled?
- Will I not be able to continue to work for the same employer till
  31st August?
- Should I inform employer before applying for student visa?
- Can I inform once decision is made on student visa?

Comment: Do you plan to stay in the UK between the end of your work and the start of your study?

Comment: Yes, I am not planning to go out of UK and enter again.

Comment: It is usual to apply well in advance for visa, with a starting date. If it works the same with these visa you should apply and mention your current visa's end and the start date of your study and ask them to make sure your visa do meet. This belongs on an other Stack Exchange site and I will move it for you.